# Sharepoint Designer does not save changes made in ItemStyle.xsl (XSL Style Library)

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I can change and save everything but when i open site, which contains Content Query Web Part showin items from my newList, webPart style isnt updated. In fact its using old ItemStyle file (i think so) which i already overwritten a few times. I thought its a common problem with designer WebSiteCache but already tried that and nothing. Im also ofc checkin in a major version and still the same. Funny thing is that everything is displayed properly for everyone else in my office :(

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint By default do setting to cache css and javascript at browser side. So to see changes in your conten Query webpart try Ctr+F5.  May be it solve your problem.